# Preposition "of" or "to": "a challenge of/to modern Europe"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am wondering which one is correct:

- "Secessionism as a challenge **of** modern Europe"
- "Secessionism as a challenge **to** modern Europe"

Thank you! :)

Comment: Depending on the intended meaning, either could be fine.

Comment: @Jason Ok, but which version sounds better to native speakers? The meaning is to see are such actions a political threat for Europe.

Comment: Again, context is required. But even with that it's likely a subjective answer—unless you can find a phrase that [Google Books Ngrams Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams) tracks and you will accept as being more common.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are possible.

The choice depends on the actual context.

Look at the entry from Merriam-Webster's Dictionary (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/challenge):

***challenge***

1: a stimulating task or problem
// looking for new challenges
(In this case we can use ***of*** to show the possession of the problem)

2: a calling to account or into question

: PROTEST

a challenge ***to*** unauthorized use of public funds
(In this case we use ***to*** to show the direction of the process)

Compare two examples from Reverso.context.net:

"Notwithstanding those efforts, the challenge ***of*** achieving sustainability remains".

"The situation presents a challenge ***to*** the international community, which must find effective means to combat that menace".